# Why is the modal not popping up on click of this div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

```js
$(function() {
 $("#pagination a").trigger('click'); // When page is loaded we trigger a click

  
 $('body').on('click','div.well well-sm',function(){
  var list = $(this);
  $('#myModal .modal-title').html('User Information');
  $('#myModal .modal-body').html(list.html());
  //$('#myModal .modal-body p').removeClass('hidden');
  // Change this bit!
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });

 
});


$('#pagination').on('click', 'a', function(e) { // When click on a 'a' element of the pagination div
 var page = this.id; // Page number is the id of the 'a' element
 var pagination = ''; // Init pagination

 $('#articleArea').html('<img src="loader-small.gif" alt="" />'); // Display a processing icon
 var data = {page: page, per_page: 4}; // Create JSON which will be sent via Ajax
 // We set up the per_page var at 4. You may change to any number you need.

 
   var displayData='';
            var articleList = [{profile_id : "1", first_name : "Jack", surname: "Crow"}];
  

   for (var j = 0; j < articleList.length; j++) {
    var gotData = articleList[j];

    displayData += '<div class="well well-sm"><p>' + gotData.profile_id + '. <b>' + gotData.first_name + '</b>' + gotData.surname + '</p>';
 //                displayData += '<p class="hidden">'+gotData.address+'</p>'+'<p class="hidden">'+gotData.gender+'</p>'+'<p class="hidden">'+gotData.dob+'</p>';
    displayData += '</div>';
    
    $('#articleArea').html(displayData);//replacing img with data
   }
   
   // Pagination system
   if (page == 1) pagination += '<div class="cell_disabled"><span>First</span></div><div class="cell_disabled"><span>Previous</span></div>';
   else pagination += '<div class="cell"><a href="#" id="1">First</a></div><div class="cell"><a href="#" id="' + (page - 1) + '">Previous</span></a></div>';

   for (var i=parseInt(page)-3; i<=parseInt(page)+3; i++) {
    if (i >= 1 && i <= data.numPage) {
     pagination += '<div';
     if (i == page) pagination += ' class="cell_active"><span>' + i + '</span>';
     else pagination += ' class="cell"><a href="#" id="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>';
     pagination += '</div>';
    }
   }

   if (page == data.numPage){
    pagination += '<div class="cell_disabled"><span>Next</span></div><div class="cell_disabled"><span>Last</span></div>';
   }
   else {
    pagination += '<div class="cell"><a href="#" id="' + (parseInt(page) + 1) + '">Next</a></div><div class="cell"><a href="#" id="' + data.numPage + '">Last</span></a></div>';
   }
   
   $('#pagination').html(pagination); // We update the pagination DIV 

 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Pagination tutorial</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
 
 <style>
 #pagination div { display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px }
 #pagination .cell a { border-radius: 3px; font-size: 11px; color: #333; padding: 8px; text-decoration:none; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color: #f8f8f8; }
 #pagination .cell a:hover { border: 1px solid #c6c6c6; background-color: #f0f0f0;  }
 #pagination .cell_active span { border-radius: 3px; font-size: 11px; color: #333; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #c6c6c6; background-color: #e9e9e9; }
 #pagination .cell_disabled span { border-radius: 3px; font-size: 11px; color: #777777; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; background-color: #ffffff; }
 </style>
</head>
 
<body>
<div id="articleArea"></div> <!-- Where articles appear -->


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
<!-- Where pagination appears -->
<div id="pagination">
 <!-- Just tell the system we start with page 1 (id=1) -->
 <!-- See the .js file, we trigger a click when page is loaded -->
 <div><a href="#" id="1"></a></div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have written this JS code to show data from the server and show it in the form of `<div>`. Each div on click is supposed to show a modal. However, here no clicks are encountered. I have written the on click on the div which are supposed to show the modals. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks okay. But only thing is, you need to invoke the modal window this way:

**Update**

You have used `'div.well well-sm'` missing a `.` before `well-sm`:

```
//----------------------------v Give a dot here.
$('body').on('click','div.well.well-sm',function(){
    var list = $(this);
    $('#myModal .modal-title').html('User Information');
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(list.html());
    $('#myModal .modal-body p').removeClass('hidden');
    // Change this bit!
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

**Working Output: http://output.jsbin.com/kebupakika**

Comment: Well.. that doesn't seem to help me. The modal still doesnt appear.

Comment: @Nevermore Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: I will create one. Just a min

Comment: I have uploaded the fiddle.

Comment: @Nevermore Does it even work? Make it work, and show the issue somewhere. Not just the code.

Comment: It gets an input from the PHP page which is a JSON array. And then the data is displayed in the form of a list. I cant make it work on Fiddle. However I will try using static data

Comment: @Nevermore Yes, static data will do. This is a client side issue.

Comment: @Nevermore You have used `'div.well well-sm'` missing a `.` before `well-sm`.

Comment: It gives me this when I click on the div.. 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: @Nevermore I fixed it in the snippet by adding bootstrap in it.

Comment: @Nevermore did you check in the snippet or did you put it in your code

Comment: @Nevermore the issue it's because of bootstrap's script not loading. Kindly check if there are any other errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks man. I replaced all my bootstrap links with new links. It works now. Thanks a lot.